# Error: "Objects are not valid as a React child" How do add atribute to component by React.createElement?

Tags: reactjs

Thank you for reading my question. I'm a new ReactJS. I get problem with using `React.createElement` to create component.
I don't know syntax if I set than one attribute when use `React.createElement` as below:

```
render() 
  {
    return React.createElement('input',
    {onChange: () => this.handleChange},
    {value: () => this.state.value}
    );
   }
```

React gives an error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child.

How do I ask many attribute in a Component where I code as this way?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createElement uses the second props argument for (supported) attributes.
So you can do this

```
render() {
return ( React.createElement('input', {
  onChange: (e) => this.handleChange(e),
  value: this.state.value
  }
 )
);
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-dirac-b5wzt)
Hope it helps

Comment: hi, i can't vote this time because Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded. :(.

Comment: oh but you can accept my answer if you can't up vote, thanks

Comment: Yeah, I've done that! But there is a problem, when i write:
value: () => this.state.value
I can't type anything in text field. 
Can you help me? ^^

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: when i write: value: () => this.state.value I can't type anything in text field. Can you help me? ^^

Comment: when i remove  value: () => this.state.value, i will type into field. And the my onChange below
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

Comment: i have updated the answer with sandbox link to give you an example, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

[`React.createElement`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) supports 3 parameters, and you're passing the thrid the wrong way, the `onChange` and `value` parameters need to go inside an object, like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    React.createElement(
      'input',
      {  onChange: () => this.handleChange, value: () => this.state.value}
      // If you need to pass a Children, will go here
    )
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
React.createElement(first, second, third)
```

React.createElement function takes three parameters:

**First**, is the type of element you want to create like `"div"`,`"span"`,`"input"`, pass as string.

**Second**, parameter is the attributes of the element like `onClick()`,`value`,etc. We gives these attributes in the form of a object like `{onClick: ()=>{}, value:'submit', id='button' }`

**Third**, parameter is the child, means the value you want to put as the innerHTML of the element. example:-

```
<div>this is the innerHTML</div>
```

so, your third parameter is the value you want to enclose inside your element tag.

the error you are getting is because you can not pass third parameter as a object, you have to defined all your attribute inside the second parameter.